# How to give permission to root user generated file by other user in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, chmod

I am trying to giving permission to root user generated file but not able to do this. Can anyone help me how to do this?

I tried:

```
echo -e 'password'> sudo chmod 777 file.txt
```

Example:

```
file.txt     rw-r--r--  root
```

Expected result:

```
file.txt     rwxrwxrwx   spate233
```

Comment: are you running this command as a root user or standard user? What is "spate233" in your question?
Can you please elaborate the request too?

Comment: If you want to change the owner, the command is `chown`, not `chmod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I can't see what you're doing by  "echo -e 'password'".
The '>' character means "output redirection", that is, bash will redirect the input of the "echo -e password" command to a file named "sudo" in the directory that you're working. The part "777 file.txt" will be appended to that file(i didn't know this, I just tested it in my PC and that's what happened).

Apart from that: if you want to access a root generated file you have to take into account that root generated files have "root" as owner and "root" as owner group.

If the user that you're trying to give permissions is a sudoer, then you can just operate using "sudo", just like you did in the example.

If it is not, and you want your user to have permissions, it would be enough to set permissions for "other" domain. You can try this:

```
sudo chmod o+rwx file.txt
```

This adds all permissions (i.e. rwx) to the other users domain.

However, if you want to give 777 permissions to the file, you just use

```
sudo chmod 777 file.txt
```

or also, if you want to use a syntax like the previous one

```
sudo chmod a+rwx file.txt
```

If it your desire, then you can also change the owner of the file. Doing this can lead to some security problems, so it is avoided if the file you are dealing with is a system file. I think this is not the case, so you can just do:

```
sudo chown user:group file
```

Where user and group are substituted with the new owner and the new group of that file.